# How to create a flash light as well as strobe effect. Need help to fix strobe effect

Tags: java, android, flashlight

I am trying to create an flash light application which contains strobe function. I have successfully achieved flash light on/off effect but I am running into trouble with strobe effect. Whenever I try to create the strobe effect the application crashes. If I remove that, it works fine.

I have one activity with a `seekbar` at the top and the on/off switch at the center. What I want to achieve is that if the user clicks on/off button the flash light should toggle on/off if the `seekbar` at the top is at 0. If the user increase the value in `seekbar` the flash light should start to strobe accordingly and if the user move the value back to 0 flashlight should remain constant. Please help me fix the error.

**LOG CAT**

```
07-23 16:54:12.610: W/dalvikvm(21210): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c15a68)
07-23 16:54:12.610: E/AndroidRuntime(21210): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2373
07-23 16:54:12.610: E/AndroidRuntime(21210): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
07-23 16:54:12.610: E/AndroidRuntime(21210):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
07-23 16:54:12.610: E/AndroidRuntime(21210):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:365)
07-23 16:54:12.610: E/AndroidRuntime(21210):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:340)
07-23 16:54:12.610: E/AndroidRuntime(21210):    at com.shyam.flashlight.StrobeController.run(StrobeController.java:29)
07-23 16:54:12.610: E/AndroidRuntime(21210):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**FlashLight.java**

```
public class FlashLight extends Activity {

ImageButton btnSwitch;
private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;
MediaPlayer mp;

StrobeController runner;
Thread bw;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash_light);

    btnSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);

    runner = StrobeController.getInstance();

    bw = new Thread(runner);
    bw.start();

    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FlashLight.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }

    getCamera();

    toggleButtonImage();

    btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*if (isFlashOn) {
                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                turnOnFlash();
            }*/

            if (isFlashOn) {
                bw = new Thread(runner);
                bw.start();
                isFlashOn = false;
            } else {
                isFlashOn = true;
                runner.requestStop = true;
            }

        }
    });

    final SeekBar skbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volume_bar);
    skbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            runner.delay = 101 - progress;
            runner.delayoff = 101 - progress;
        }
    });

}

private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }

        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}

private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }

        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}

private void playSound() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(FlashLight.this, R.raw.light_switch_off);
    } else {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(FlashLight.this, R.raw.light_switch_on);
    }
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    mp.start();
}

private void toggleButtonImage() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_switch_on);
    } else {
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_switch_off);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.stopPreview();
    isFlashOn = false;

    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    Log.d("Camera", "Back Pressed");
}

}
```

**StrobeController.java**

```
public class StrobeController implements Runnable {

protected StrobeController() { }

public static StrobeController getInstance() {
    return (instance == null ? instance = new StrobeController() : instance);
}

private static StrobeController instance;
public volatile boolean requestStop = false;
public volatile boolean isRunning = false;
public volatile int delay = 10;
public volatile int delayoff = 500;
public volatile String errorMessage = "";

@Override
public void run() {
    if (isRunning)
        return;

    requestStop = false;
    isRunning = true;

    Camera cam = Camera.open();

    Parameters pon = cam.getParameters(), poff = cam.getParameters();

    pon.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    poff.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

    while (!requestStop) {
        try {
            cam.setParameters(pon);
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            cam.setParameters(poff);
            Thread.sleep(delayoff);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            requestStop = true;
            errorMessage = "Error setting camera flash status. Your device may be unsupported.";
        }
    }

    cam.release();

    isRunning = false;
    requestStop = false;
}

}
```

Comment: Look at the output of 'logcat' which will tell you where the exception was thrown, or post what it puts out here

Comment: @Kerry Please see the EDIT. I have pasted output from logcat.

Answer (score 1):

I notice the exception is being thrown at line 29:

> at com.shyam.flashlight.StrobeController.run(StrobeController.java:29)

Is line 29 `Camera cam = Camera.open();`?

You have the correct permissions as described [here?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)
Also, are you trying to open a null camera? Look at what line 29 is in StrobeController class.

Comment: I have following permission added in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>`

Comment: Line 29 in `StrobeController` is `Camera cam = Camera.open();`

Comment: I've not really used a Camera device n android but googling around it seems this might be an issue with not releasing the Camera previously? I'd google the Exception text and trawl through the various answers